# Linq Left Join: Можно ли оптимизировать linq запрос?

Tags: c#, оптимизация, linq

Мне необходимо показать пользователю *представление*, информация для отображении находится в разных таблицах.

Для *упрощения* я получаю данные несколькими запросами, после этого я склеиваю все эти данные при помощи *левых соединений*.

`linq` запрос выглядит так:

```
var operations = _context.Set<Operation>()
                    .Include(x=>x.Product)
                    .ToList();

var timeWorks = _context.Set<OperationItem>()
                    .Where()
                    .ToList();

var attachments = _context.Set<OperationItem>()
                    .Where()
                    .ToList();

var result = operations
                 .GroupJoin(attachments, o=>o.Id, i=>i.OperationId, (l,r)=> new {Operation = l, Attachment = r})
                 .SelectMany(x=>x.Attachment.DefaultIfEmpty(), (l,r)=>new {Operation = l.Operation, Attachment = r})
                 .GroupJoin(timeWorks, o=>o.Operation.OperationId, i=>i.OperationId, (l,r)=> new {Operation = l.Operation, Attachment = l.Attaqchment, TimeWork = r.Sum(_=>_.TimeWork)})
                 .Select(x=> new OperationList
                 {
                     //Собираем окончательное представление
                 })
                 .ToList();
```

Все работает так как необходимо, но мне не нравится что для каждого *левого соединения* приходится *прокидывать* результат предыдущего соединения:

```
new {Operation = l.Operation, Attachment = l.Attaqchment, TimeWork = r.Sum(_=>_.TimeWork)}
```

Подскажите может я что то делаю не так и можно это сделать проще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для исключения "прокидывания" можно воспользоваться встроенной формой linq - в таком случае компилятор позаботится о прокидывании сам:

```
var result = from operation in operations
             join attachment in attachments on operation.Id equals attachment.OperationId into attachmentsgroup
             from attachment in attachmentsgroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join timeWork in timeWorks on operation.Id equals timeWork.OperationId into timeWorksgroup
             let timeWork = timeWorksgroup.Sum(_ => _.TimeWork)
             select new OperationList {
               // ...
             };
```

Но, вообще говоря, left join через group join - это трюк, который пригоден для применения только в запросах к базе, где left join является "родным" оператором.

Для запросов к объектам все делается намного проще!

```
var operations = _context.Set<Operation>()
                    .Include(x=>x.Product)
                    .AsEnumerable();

var timeWorks = _context.Set<OperationItem>()
                    .Where()
                    .ToLookup(x => x.OperationId);

var attachments = _context.Set<OperationItem>()
                    .Where()
                    .ToLookup(x => x.OperationId);

var result = from operation in operations
             from attachment in attachments[operation.Id].DefaultIfEmpty()
             let timeWork = timeWorks[operation.Id].Sum(_ => _.TimeWork)
             select new OperationList {
               // ...
             };
```

Comment: @Bald а второй-то параметр зачем?

Comment: @Bald https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549073(v=vs.110).aspx Не знаю, где вы искали, но определенно искали плохо.

Comment: @Bald Откуда у вас взялись Key1 и Key2?

Comment: @Bald и почему мой пример не заработал? В чем это проявилось?